# f:validateRequiered doesn't work as expected

Tags: jsf-2

I have just created a NetBeans project with JSF 2.0 and I have a problem with f:validateRequired. The bean

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class TestBean {
    private String value;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String action() {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

and the page

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <h:outputStylesheet name="css/stylesheet.css" />
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <div id="content">
                Value:
                <h:message for="test" />
                <h:inputText value="#{testBean.value}" id="test">
                    <f:validateRequired />
                </h:inputText>
                <br/>
                <h:commandButton action="#{testBean.action}" value="Action" />
            </div>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

seems to be allright, but the h:message isn't there until I supply the requered="true" attribute on the inputText. What I am missing? Why the validation does not occure whithout the requered="true" attribute?

Comment: Did you try to see if `f:validateLength` works as expected?

Comment: @BheshGurung `f:validateLength minimum="1"` does not work either if the input is empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured the answer: fields with empty input are not validated at all by default. If you wish to validate such field you have to set `required=true`. See [UIInput.validateValue() JavaDoc](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.0/javadocs/javax/faces/component/UIInput.html#validateValue%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext,%20java.lang.Object%29)

You can enable the validation of empty fields by setting the `javax.faces.VALIDATE_EMPTY_FIELDS` context parameter to `true`. See [JavaDoc](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.0/javadocs/javax/faces/component/UIInput.html#VALIDATE_EMPTY_FIELDS_PARAM_NAME). After doing that the example above works as expected.

Comment: @BalusC I am pretty sure the parameter isn't set. The default in this case is to check for Bean Validation. If Bean Validation is not present in the runtime environment, the validation will not proceed. See [UIInput.validateValue() JavaDoc](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.0/javadocs/javax/faces/component/UIInput.html#validateValue%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext,%20java.lang.Object%29)

Answer (score 2):

I know this post is kind of old, but  I'm using MyFaces and apparently `javax.faces.VALIDATE_EMPTY_FIELDS` is set to false by default.